# RequiredFieldValidator not working for tow Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tow Dropdownlist in my web page as follows.

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="JobDDL" runat="server" class="form-control" ValidationGroup="gg" >
  </asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="-1" ID="Req_ID" Display="Dynamic" 
                                                    ValidationGroup="gg" runat="server" ControlToValidate="JobDDL"
                                                    Text="*"  ErrorMessage="أختر الفرع من فضلك"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


<asp:DropDownList ID="BranchDDL" runat="server" class="form-control">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="BranchDDL"   ErrorMessage="أختر الفرع من فضلك" InitialValue="اختر من فضلك" ForeColor="red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

frist Dropdownlist RequiredFieldValidator (ID="JobDDL") not work . The second RequiredFieldValidatorworks(ID="BranchDDL")

Comment: could be because of the `ValidationGroup="gg"` post the other section of design code

Comment: `InitialValue="-1"` looks fishy here.

Comment: i do it . but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add Display="Dynamic" and Initial value="Select" in Required Field Validator

if your dropdown list first element has **select** values please Add Initial Value="Select" in Required Field Validator.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="Please Select Type" InitialValue="--Select--" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CC0000" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Masha Allah Good